# Why If $x^2=-\frac{1}{3}$ then $x=\pm\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If $x^2=-\frac{1}{3}$ then $x=\pm\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{3}$ according to my text book.

I understand that $x=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{1}{3}}$ but do not fully grasp how to express this as $\pm\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{3}$

I understand that $i$ is $\sqrt{-1}$

As far as I can get with my understanding starting from:
$$x=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{-3}}$$
$$x=\pm\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}i}$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt{3}$$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $x=\pm\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{3}$

[Edit]

From the comments I now know that $-\frac{1}{3}$ = $\frac{-1}{3}$

Taking that back into my working I still arrive at a different answer:
$$x=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-1}{3}}$$
$$x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{3}$$
$$x=\pm\frac{i}{3}$$

How can I get to $x=\pm\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{3}$

Comment: I dont understad how you've gone from $x=\pm\sqrt{-\frac13}$ to $x=\pm\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{-3}}$.

Comment: Its not $\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{-3}}$ it is : $\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: I thought that when you take the root of a division as a whole that it's equivalent as taking the root of the numerator and dividing by the root of the denominator?

Comment: Also from $x=\pm\frac i{\sqrt 3i}$ to $x=\pm\sqrt 3$, but inspecting a passage coming after a very likely mistake of algebra is less interesting.

Comment: @DougFir Even so, $-\frac13\ne\frac{-1}{-3}$.

Comment: OP, you've to be warned before using some calculations in the complex domain $$  \sqrt(4) = \sqrt{-2*-2} \neq \sqrt{-2} * \sqrt{-2} $$

Comment: With response to the edit... you went from $\sqrt{\dfrac{-1}{3}}$ to $\dfrac{\sqrt{-1}}{3}$.  This is wrong.  The $3$ should also be under a root of some sort.

Comment: ah right, of course! thanks

Comment: Now... as alluded to elsewhere, in your original attempt and the next step in your current attempt once this correction was made, and it doesn't look like you've confirmed your understanding of yet, you will be with something like $\dfrac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$.  In your original working it looked like you thought $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ was equal to $\sqrt{3}$.  It is not.  Compare... $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4}}=0.5\neq 2 = \sqrt{4}$.  Instead, you have $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\times 1 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\times\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

Comment: @JMoravitz yep, got that thanks for highlighting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you did wrong was the fact that

$$-\frac13=\frac{-1}{3}=\frac{1}{-3}$$

and NOT

$$-\frac13=\frac{-1}{-3}$$

After the editing the problem is:

$$\sqrt{-\frac13}=\sqrt{\frac{-1}{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

Comment: Got it, thanks Arnaldo

Comment: Please see my edit too

Comment: @DougFir: Please, check my editing!

Comment: This is great, thanks, I understand and can follow

Answer (score 1):

After your edit; compare your simplification with

\begin{align}
x&=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{1}{3}}\\
x&=\pm\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{3}}\\
x&=\pm\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\\
x&=\pm i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{{3}}
\end{align}
The last step is achieved since
\begin{align}
\sqrt{3} \sqrt{3} = 3
\end{align}
Thus
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

Comment: i'm confused because on your second step doesn't that contradict the comments i had where only one of numerator or denominator are negative, not both?

Comment: No, the last step there is just a pure arithmetical step; there is nothing really to simplify.

Comment: @Kevin the OP is referring to $\sqrt{-\dfrac{1}{3}}$ going to $\dfrac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{-3}}$ which is incorrect, as already pointed out elsewhere in this thread.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh heck, I see my typo has massively confused matters....I'll edit. Thanks JM

Comment: @DougFir Hi there, please see edit. I annoyingly left in a negative sign which has now been removed. Sorry for confusion.